# Extract data from 1x1 cell array

Tags: matlab

I read a .txt file into a 1x1 cell array using *textscan*. How to I extract certain data from that 1x1 cell array?

The .txt file has mixed format data.

The code I have so far:

```html
%% Import Safir output file
    
    FileName="PROOV_6.txt";
    tic

%% Read the txt file
        FID = fopen(FileName, 'r');
            if FID == -1
                error('Cannot open file')
            end
        Data = textscan(FID, '%s', 'delimiter', '\n', 'whitespace', ' ' );
        CStr = Data{1};
        fclose(FID);
        
%% Find all row numbers that contain the string
        Index = strfind(CStr, 'TOTAL TEMPERATURES');
        IndexA = find(not(cellfun('isempty', Index)));
                           
%% Loop through CStr accessing matrices between strings "TOTAL TEMPERATURES"

%% ---------- 
       
%% Save the file again
        FID = fopen(FileName, 'w');
            if FID == -1
                error('Cannot open file')
            end
        fprintf(FID, '%s\n', CStr{:});
        fclose(FID);
    toc
```

I will also provide a link to the .txt file:
[PROOV_6.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ImgxyQSMCjJBOt8_s5IEm-Hek2pGP7C/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Use `{}` indexing to get a value out of a cell array. That there is only one cell makes no difference. `mycell{1}`.